# Implement a method returning "week-data"

Tags: java

In my application I'm implementing several service methods returning data related to a week period.

So I have several methods similar to `getDataByDateInterval(Date from, Date to)` but I actually need to always retrieve data for a week: from Monday to Sunday (or from Sunday to Saturday, if you prefer).

In this case, is it more correct to have a method with a single `Date` argument and then calculate week date span?

I'd like to find an elegant and correct way to implement these methods.

Comment: Seems like [Joda's Weeks could help](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Weeks.html)

Comment: Eh, `Weeks` is useful, but it's little more than a wrapper for an integer (number of weeks).  Not sure it's applicable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is to chain your methods:

```
getDataByDateInterval(Date from, Date to) {
    //...
}

getDataByWeek(Date to) {
    // Calculate 'from' date (minus 7 days)
    return getDataByDateInterval(from, to);
}
```

This approach keeps your interface clear but prevents you violating the DRY principle.

Comment: This calculation is trivial with Joda-Time: `new LocalDate().minus(Weeks.ONE)`.

Comment: @dimo414 Whilst I am a big fan of Joda (and Guava as mentioned by another poster), the question is more related to class/interface design as opposed to the underlying implementation of date calculations.

Comment: Totally, my comment wasn't a criticism, merely providing a possible way to "Calculate 'from' date (minus 7 days)" as you describe.

Comment: @dimo414 Sorry to cause confusion. I didn't take it as a criticism. More to explain why I am not going to edit my answer to include implementation detail.

Comment: Agreed, no need to include one possible implementation detail in a high-level answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have had great success handling date-range queries using Guava's `Range` class.  For a while I tried creating methods like `getDataByDateInterval(Date from, Date to)` but these are cumbersome to work with, particularly to keep track of whether `from` and `to` should be inclusive or exclusive in any particular case.

I use two interfaces very heavily in my project, `Dated` and `DatedLookup`:

```
public interface Dated {
    public LocalDate getDate();
}

public interface DatedLookup<T extends Dated> {
    public List<T> queryRange(Range<LocalDate> range);
}
```

`Range` also lets you query for all data, or data unbound on one side (e.g. `(-∞..2000-1-1)` will query everything before 2000).  This introduces some of it's own complexities (you have to check that the range has endpoints before trying to get them) but I think this is a feature more than a burden.

You can also, as an implementation detail, know the bounds of all you data and thereby bound the inputs your user sends, e.g.:

```
public class MyClass<T> imlements DatedLookup<T> {
  // We know there's no data outside this range
  private static final Range<LocalDate> MAX_RANGE = 
      Range.closed(new LocalDate(2010,1,1), new LocalDate());

  @Override
  public List<T> queryRange(Range<LocalDate> range) {
    // range could be Range.all(), meaning it has no bounds
    range = MAX_RANGE.intersection(range);
    // now we guarenteee range has bounds, and can safely call
    LocalDate start = range.lowerEndpoint();
    ....
  }

  // We can also define useful wrappers, like
  public List<T> queryOneWeekBack(LocalDate lastDay) {
    return queryRange(Range.openClosed(lastDate.minus(Weeks.ONE), lastDay);
  }
}
```

You'll need [`Range`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) (and the awesome [`RangeSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html) and [`RangeMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html)) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), and [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) from [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (or [LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) in [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29)).  These two libraries add amazingly useful functionality to almost any project.  You're crippling yourself if you aren't using them.

Answer (score 0):

I like @JamesB approach, but the actual calculation of dates can be done using `Joda`

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime today = new DateTime();
        DateTime nextWeek = today.plusWeeks(1);
        DateTime lastWeek = today.minusWeeks(1);
        System.out.println("Last Week: " + lastWeek.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        System.out.println("Today: " + today.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        System.out.println("Next Week: " + nextWeek.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

    }
}
```

Which yields:

```
Last Week: 07/22/2014
Today: 07/29/2014
Next Week: 08/05/2014
```

Comment: Unless you intentionally want to work with times and time zones (and generally, you don't want to do that), you should prefer `LocalDate` for date-math and other "abstract" date operations.

Comment: And if you *do* want to work with times and time zones, then you might want to add a call to [`withTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) to set the time to first moment of the day (generally `00:00:00.000` but not always).